# Ctrl+Tab to switch tabs for puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, tabs, puppeteer

I have a massive amount of tabs, and when a certain event happens, I want to switch to the next tab. I should be able to use the `bringToFront();` method.

I tried this:

```
await page.keyboard.down('ControlLeft');
await page.keyboard.press('Tab');
```

but nothing happened, so I tried:

```
await page.keyboard.down('ControlLeft');
await page.keyboard.press('KeyA');
```

but it selected all the contents. It looks like I am using a wrong keyword for tab  button.

To clarify, I am launching the group of tabs using cluster, so I can't use the `bringToFront` method, since there is no `page1` and `page2`; there is only 1 page, and the same script is launched multiple times attached to a previously opened Chrome window.

Comment: It seems that there is a typo in the question. Can or can you *not* use `bringToFront`? If not, why?

Comment: so the bringtoFront require to launch multiple pages/browser form the same script  for ex     const page = await browser.newPage();
             const page1 = await browser.newPage();
while what am doing am  using cluster to spawn multiple instances of puppeteer so that wouldnt work

Comment: well, you say that you have massive amount of tabs anyway, so why not bringToFront them?

Comment: because then i have to do  await page1.bringToFront();
    blockingWait(1);
    await page2.bringToFront();
    blockingWait(1);  which i cant since every instance/tab is independent

Comment: I guess you have to take a step back and tell us more about the setup you have, what you're trying to do just so we can avoid [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/399876).

Comment: to be accurate of how am using puppeteer , am connecting it to a chrome using --remote-debuggin-port so am connecting multiple instances

Comment: and each instance is launched via cluster so the tabs aren't launched from the same puppeteer script

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231882/discussion-between-dumbuser-and-vaviloff).